Display page in nextjs server side
I'm using Next.JS 14, I want to show a page to the client if the request is coming from a browser but if it's not from a browser redirect to another website.
Base on this code section I've done the redirect part but there isn't any documentation for showing the page.
I'd appreciate if you can help me out how to show the page.
Thanks.
// for GET method 
export async function GET(request) {
    const headersList = headers();
    if(!headersList.get("Accept").includes("text/html")) {
        return NextResponse.redirect("https://example.com");
    }
    
    return Page(); //LAYOUT
}


While the previous answer should work, if performance is a concern you can also try setting up a middleware by creating a middleware.js file at the root of your project.
So for instance the middleware file should look something like the following:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request) {
  const acceptHeader = request.headers.get('accept') || '';

  if (!acceptHeader.includes('text/html')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect('https://example.com');
  }

  // Proceed to render the page as usual
  return NextResponse.next();
}

Plus a config object if you want to limit to specific paths
export const config = { matcher: '/your-specific-path/:path*' };

By checking Header, secFetchSite, secFetchMode, userAgent we can confirm if the request is from browser
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import ClientComponentfrom './ClientComponent'

const headersList = headers()
  
  // get relevant headers
  const userAgent = headersList.get('user-agent')?.toLowerCase() || ''
  const acceptHeader = headersList.get('Accept') || ''
  const secFetchMode = headersList.get('Sec-Fetch-Mode')
  const secFetchSite = headersList.get('Sec-Fetch-Site')
  
  // browser detection logic
  const isBrowser = 
    // check if it's a common browser user-agent
    (userAgent.includes('mozilla/') || userAgent.includes('chrome/') || 
     userAgent.includes('safari/') || userAgent.includes('edge/') ||
     userAgent.includes('firefox/')) &&
    // modern browsers send these security headers
    secFetchMode === 'navigate' &&
    // should be from same-origin or none (direct navigation)
    (secFetchSite === 'same-origin' || secFetchSite === 'none') &&
    // Should accept HTML
    acceptHeader.includes('text/html')

  // if not a browser, redirect
  if (!isBrowser) {
    return NextResponse.redirect('https://abcxyz.com.io')
  }

  return (
    <main className="p-4">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      {/* your client component will render here */}
      <ClientComponent />
    </main>
  )
}


Thank you but my problem is not finding out if the request is coming from the browser but it's that how can I show a client component to the user without redirecting.

In return, just show the component. Edited above code, let me know if it helps.
